# CHAINLINK NODE: How might I approach fixing "unable to lock ORM" errors?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, orm, blockchain

I am not overly familiar with the process of setting up a chainlink node. I have done so today, but am running into an issue. On the very last step, when attempting to start the chainlink node I put the following into the command line:

```
cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink local n
```

When this runs the pulls all say "pull complete"

I am getting the following ORM errors:

> 2020-10-15T22:07:30Z [ERROR] unable to lock ORM: dial tcp
> 127.0.0.1:5432: connec                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             t: connection refused logger/default.go:139
> stacktrace=github.com/smartcontrac
> tkit/chainlink/core/logger.Error
>
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203 2020-10-15T22:07:30Z [FATAL]
> Unable to initialize ORM: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432:
> connect: connection refused unable to open  for gorm DB

I am not sure what might be the issue. Could someone point me in the direction I might start in the debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`[ERROR] unable to lock ORM` is the default message given when the data is not able to be reached, and it also don't see another user with a lock. You can see the reason it can't connect to the ORM is because: `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connec t: connection refused` To fix, you can try a number of different things:

#### 1. Try to access the postgress database using the parameters of the `DATABASE_URL`

If you can't get into the DB with the parameters of the `DATABASE_URL` there might be something wrong with that. You can see if you can connect by [downloading the psql client](https://www.postgresql.org/download/). If on ubuntu you can use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

and then running something like `psql -h IP_HERE -U USER_HERE` and then entering your password

#### 2. Add `--network host` for local databases

If you are running your node/database locally you'll have to add `--network host` to your chainlink docker command.

#### 3. Try `localhost`, `172.17.0.1`, or use a cloud DB if you're using a mac.

Docker is a little tricky when it comes to IPs. If you are running a local DB and you are trying to use `127.0.0.1`, you may want to try `localhost`. On a mac, you'll run into issues since the docker gateway doesn't play nicely with macos, and easy work around is to get a database URL from a cloud database like on heroku, GCP, or AWS.

If none of these work for you, please add a comment and we can update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing Patrick's video, I noticed that that I was copying the Public IP, when in fact, the private IP from GCP is what you need you use in you command to run docker