# Chainlink node error: password authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: chainlink

I get two errors when I look to start a Chainlink node. Here they are:

> [ERROR] unable to lock ORM: pq: password authentication failed for
> user "root" logger/default.go:155
> stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Errorf
>
> [FATAL] Unable to initialize ORM: pq: password authentication failed
> for user "root" unable to open postgresql://:@10.24.64.5:5432/ for
> gorm DB

Then, I am also unable to connect to the GUI

Comment: It's likely that your password is incorrect for the database you're using. If you're using special characters, you'll have to use the URL encoded version of those characters in your postgres URL. Could you try with url encoded characters? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: Thanks for the Response!!! I just tried that.. my PW has three exclamation points at the end so I replaced them with %20%20%20. Same results... I can post the whole terminal chain if you think that will help!

Comment: Nice! Glad that helped. It also looks like you don’t have a user in your database URL, as it’s defaulting to root. Do you know the user of the database?

Comment: Or, if you’d like, put your Postgres database URL here and obfuscate the password and IP address

Comment: echo "DATABASE_URL=postgresql://chainlink-db-user:$PASS@10.24.xx.x:5432/chainlink-kovan-db" >> ~/chainlink-kovan/ .env

Comment: I just double checked the user name on the database and it is spelled correctly..

Comment: echo "ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=42
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://:@10.24.xx.x:5432/" > ~/.chainlink-kovan/.env

Comment: Here's my Env... Also thinking this might not be correct

Comment: Your .env doesn’t have a database user for the database URL

Comment: Thanks I added the user but it still won't accept the PW.... it now shows the user name instead of "root". I think I'm gonna start fresh and use a less complicated PW...

Comment: Ping back here when you solve it? I think it's likely that you just can't connect to your database. 

If you can't connect with `psql -h IP_HERE -U USER_HERE` that might also be an issue. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380656/chainlink-node-how-might-i-approach-fixing-unable-to-lock-orm-errors for more information

Comment: Ok making progress... I got to "create new password" I did but still not gettin into the UI... I see this message that might be related.  panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0xdba632]

Comment: Could you make this a new stackoverflow question with this error? And post the whole stack trave

Comment: done! thanks again for your help!